# Cannot use multiple index fields in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi

In using more than 1 index field like this:
   stocktable.INDEXFIELDnames:='NUMBER;PRE';

I get the error: "No index for fields 'NUMBER;PRE'.

Using them separately works.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a BDE TTable, correct?  Have you tried defining an index in those fields using  the `IndexDefs` prpoerty of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an index to your table before you can do what you want.

It's best to do this in a separate project from your current one because the BDE can be very fussy about this kind of operation, which needs to be done while the table is not in use.

- Close your existing project and restart Delphi
- Start a new project
- Drop a TQuery and a TButton on the project's form
- Set the TQuery's `Database` name to the name of your database

Then define the OnClick handler for the TButton like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Query1.SQL.Text :='Create Index ByNumberAndPre on  StockTable (Number,Pre) ';
  Query1.ExecSQL;
  ShowMessage('Done');
end;
```

This assumes, of course, that the table's name (in the database) is 'StockTable'.

The '(Number,Pre)'  specifies the order of the columns in the index.  Note that the separator is a comma, not a semi-colon.

Compile and run the project and click the button.  Assuming you get the 'Done' message,
close this project and re-open your existing one.  Now, you should be able to click in the TTable's `IndexName` field and select `ByNumberAndPre` from the pull-down list.

Btw, these days, probably the best reference on working with SQL on BDE tables is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/create-index-for-paradox?view=sql-server-2017

Below is the code of a sample project that would allow you to play around with this idea.  You would need to add for a blank form a TTable, a TDBGrid and TDBNavigator connected to the TTable via a TDataSource, a TQuery and a number of TButtons (which would then need connecting to the click-handlers).  I've called the table "StockTable2" so that the project doesn't interfere with your existing table.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Query1.SQL.Text :='Create Index MyPrimary on  StockTable (Number,Pre) ';
  Query1.ExecSQL;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnCreateTableClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  Query1.SQL.Text :='Create Table "Stocktable2.db" ('#13#10
+ ' id int, pre char(8), number int, CONSTRAINT z PRIMARY KEY (id))';
  Query1.ExecSQL;

 Query1.SQL.Text := 'Create Index ByNumberAndPre on  StockTable2 (Number,Pre)';
 Query1.ExecSQL;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDropClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Query1.SQL.Text :='drop table Stocktable2';
  Query1.ExecSQL;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Table1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,
  n : Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 100 do begin
    n := Trunc(Random(100));
    Table1.InsertRecord([i, Chr(Ord('A') + Random(26)), n]);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnUseIndexClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Table1.IndexName := 'ByNumberAndPre';
end;
```

Comment: Did this answer your q?

Comment: I will get around to the suggestions above and let know. I am sure that it will be the solution. Many Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you could be so kind as to accept my answer by clicking the "tick" icon on its left ...